# After changing the permissions remains 2 instance application (Android)

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

Please tell me, who can faced.

Run applications and then you come into as far as possible on the screen (or at least to the second screen using fragments) and then in the settings the device turns off permission (any) (in the logs can see how the Kill app) and when to go back to the application, the application starts again, but the previous instance the MainActivityis not killed, it found out few clicks of a Back.

This is normal behavior?
And to make so that if the application starts again to kill the old instance application and eventually by pressing the back button, the application was closed?

The Nexus 7 (2013) 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the application is doing what it should.

On my Nexus 5 (Android 6.0.1) if I use the back button to exit an application, it is still listed in my running applications. You can destroy activities by calling 'finish()' on them, which you could do with the back button if that's what you need.